# How to 'fill' CSS Grid columns?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-grid

I've been searching SO (and internet) for an answer without success.
I'm kind of new to CSS Grid layouts.

Consider the following truncated `HTML` markup:
The numbers of rows and columns are fixed and known.

```html
<div class="wrapper">

   <div class="ISOday-1">Monday</div>
   <div class="ISOday-2">Tuesday</div>
   <div class="ISOday-3">Wednesday</div>
   <div class="ISOday-4">Thursday</div>
   <div class="ISOday-5">Friday</div>
   <div class="ISOday-6">Saturday</div>

   <label class="ISOday-1">09:00</label>
   <label class="ISOday-1">09:30</label>
   ...
   <label class="ISOday-2">09:00</label>
   <label class="ISOday-2">09:30</label>
   ...
   <label class="ISOday-3">09:00</label>
   <label class="ISOday-3">09:30</label>
   ...
   <label class="ISOday-4">09:00</label>
   <label class="ISOday-4">09:30</label>
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

And the `CSS`:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [monday] auto [tuesday] auto [wednesday] auto [thursday] auto [friday] auto [saturday] auto;
}

.ISOday-1 { grid-column: monday;}
.ISOday-2 { grid-column: tuesday; }
.ISOday-3 { grid-column: wednesday; }
.ISOday-4 { grid-column: thursday; }
.ISOday-5 { grid-column: friday; } 
.ISOday-6 { grid-column: saturday; }
```

The result is this:

[image]
The problem is that:

- For Tuesday, I have 4 empty row *at the beginning*.
- For Wednesday, I have 8...

I have tried many CSS Grid attributes, but I'm not able to make all time slots start at **row 2**. Do you have any clue?

Comment: just remove your empty rows from your template? and add everywhere 1 empty row than you get what u want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grid-auto-flow: column`

> **column**
>
> Is a keyword specifying that the auto-placement algorithm places items, by **filling each column in turn**, adding new columns as necessary.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)

*Note: This works in your case because **the length of each column would be the same**. If this is the NOTcase, an alternative structure / layout mechansism is recommended.*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [monday] auto [tuesday] auto [wednesday] auto [thursday] auto [friday] auto [saturday] auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.ISOday-1 {
  grid-column: monday;
}

.ISOday-2 {
  grid-column: tuesday;
}

.ISOday-3 {
  grid-column: wednesday;
}

.ISOday-4 {
  grid-column: thursday;
}

.ISOday-5 {
  grid-column: friday;
}

.ISOday-6 {
  grid-column: saturday;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="ISOday-1">Monday</div>
  <div class="ISOday-2">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="ISOday-3">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="ISOday-4">Thursday</div>
  <div class="ISOday-5">Friday</div>
  <div class="ISOday-6">Saturday</div>

  <label class="ISOday-1">09:00</label>
  <label class="ISOday-1">09:30</label>

  <label class="ISOday-2">09:00</label>
  <label class="ISOday-2">09:30</label>

  <label class="ISOday-3">09:00</label>
  <label class="ISOday-3">09:30</label>

  <label class="ISOday-4">09:00</label>
  <label class="ISOday-4">09:30</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify it like this.

Its not the exact way how you did it but it reduces the amout of classes needed.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;

  width: 700px;
  background: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [monday] auto [tuesday] auto [wednesday] auto [thursday] auto [friday] auto [saturday] auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

   <div>Monday</div>
   <div>Tuesday</div>
   <div>Wednesday</div>
   <div>Thursday</div>
   <div>Friday</div>
   <div>Saturday</div>
  
  <label> 9:00</label>
  <label> 9:00</label>
  <label> 9:00</label>
  <label> 9:00</label>
  <label> 9:00</label>
  <label> 9:00</label>
  
  <label> 9:30</label>
  <label> 9:30</label>
  <label> 9:30</label>
  <label> 9:30</label>
  <label> 9:30</label>
  <label> 9:30</label>
  
  <label> 10:00</label>
  <label> 10:00</label>
  <label> 10:00</label>
  <label> 10:00</label>
  <label> 10:00</label>
  <label> 10:00</label>
</div>
```