# CSS grid has empty items

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to force the items in column 2 to be in the same rows as the corresponding items in column 1. The 'A' items to be in the first row, 'B' items in the second row, etc.

I thought that by assigning `grid-column` to my items that it would force the items into the columns and then fill in any blanks. But instead it's leaving empty space.

How do I explicitly set the column number without leaving empty items?

[image]

https://codepen.io/ohthepain/pen/JjBYaVo

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.grid-column-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.grid-column-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
        Column 1 A
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
        Column 1 B
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
        Column 1 C
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
        Column 2 A
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
        Column 2 B
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
        Column 2 C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do, this is the updated `CSS`

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 4fr;
}
```

Overall you have this.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 4fr;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
                Column 1 A
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
                Column 2 A
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-1">
                Column 1 B
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
                Column 2 B
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
                Column 1 C
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-column-2">
                Column 2 C
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankit for the super-fast response! I have edited my question as it was a bit unclear. I am trying to get the A items onto the same row.

Comment: I am trying to control which column each item goes into.

Comment: Can you give an example I am not getting what exactly you want.

Comment: If I change the order of the items in the html then they go into different columns. The problem I am trying to solve is part of a React project where I don't have control over the order in which the items are generated. That's why I want to make the column numbers explicit. So I should be able to put the items in any order and have them appear in the correct columns.

Comment: If you dont have the control over the order then just html is not going to help , you have to write JS logic according to the incoming data. It is not practical to use only HTML.

Comment: I am just trying to get rid of the empty items

Answer (score 0):

It's `grid-auto-flow: column;`. I found the answer here: [How to 'fill' CSS Grid columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855599/how-to-fill-css-grid-columns)

Answer (score -1):

Use this below code and you can fulfill your requirement.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 1 A
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 1 B
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 1 C
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 2 A
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 2 B
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    Column 2 C
  </div>
</div>
```